Dotnet pack / nuget pack - How to simply pack multiple projects into one package (all projects included in .csproj) & test it?
there are few similar discussions on the internet about this, but all of them are old ones and without complex solution "from A-Z", only few specific problems.
I would like to pack multiple projects inside one package and I cannot, because Microsoft totally ignores this issue since 2016.
The nuget pack is no longer recommended, but it had the -IncludeReferencedProjects flag. So I would like to do it with dotnet pack command.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack
Here is the long (470 comments) stroy about this issue:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891
or just some other discussion:
Pack multiple assemblies with dotnet pack
But could you tell me the ways to simply pack my main project and all the projects included in the .csproj file (<PackageReference Include="">)?

After spending few days I can address all the issues:

If you don't want to change .csproj, then only way is to create multiple packages.
Don't use Azure for testing purposes, it's too much trouble. Create local NuGet feed (create folder anywhere on your PC, in Visual or Rider add new feed, name it "LocalNugetFeed" and point to the directory you created previously. And just put your dotnet pack results (.nupkg files inside this folder).
Remember that NuGet packages are stored/cached locally, so if you modify & create packages with the same name (default one, so like my.package.1.0.0-dev.nupkg), you must use dotnet nuget locals all --clear. Otherwise even after installing the "updated" version to your project/solution, it would still get the old one from the cache.
Your package must include otherProject.dll. To check it, just copy-paste your .nupkg, change file extension to .zip, open it, go to lib/net<your-version> and check if there are all your .dll. So if you've got main project and 5 <PackageReferences> to your local projects, you need to have 5+1 .dll`.

And now we'll go to to the main problem, so how to pack multiple projects into one package:

Create pack.props file in your solution (the best would be just in your main-project), just below the main-project.csproj. Or if you want to use it globally, then create it in your solution:


Copy-paste this code, don't change it:
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'All'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>


Modify your .csproj (adjust it to yourself):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Import Project="pack.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>warnings</Nullable>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <Description>My Description</Description>
    <Authors>My Authors</Authors>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>




Or eventually use .nuspec file:

https://medium.com/@dinko.pavicic/nuget-packaging-bundling-multiple-projects-with-nuspec-41547bb2b92f

dotnet pack -p:NuspecFile=MyFile.Bundled.nuspec -o nupkgs

